# android get restful api always timeout

Tags: java, android, rest, httpclient

I use `httpclient(apache)` to get a restful API when developing an Android app,just like

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://9.123.151.73:4414/apiv1/data");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

and the xml,I have set the permission:

```
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
```

but it always timeout.

Then I try these cases:

1. Open the url in browser,it works
2. New a simple java project with the same code, it works
3. Replace the url with other rest API ,such as:
   `http://api.search.yahoo.co/NewsSearchService/V1/`, works

So, could you give me any advices for this problem,I wonder why the rest API can not be used in Android app,what is the mistake?

Comment: Is the url correct with "//http..."?

Comment: sorry,it's correct in my project,3q

Comment: @wanftian Have you solved your problem? I am facing the same issue. If you have solved it then please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Akash,the problem still exists, i have to use an another way for my project.at last i use a server as a proxy to get the rest data,but it does not the best way. i will be very pleasure if you can share the answer when you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it is due to the permission not set to make network connections. Here is what  you need to add to your AndroidMainfest.xml file to allow access to the internet:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Here is the permission description:

> **INTERNET**  Allows applications to open network sockets.

You can check more about the permission from the link:

Here is how you can set the permission if you are using eclipse:

> If you are using the Eclipse ADT plugin for your development, open
>   "AndroidManifest.xml" in the Android Manifest Editor (should be the
>   default action for opening androidmanifest.xml from the project files
>   list), select the "Permissions" tab along the bottom of the editor
>   (Manifest - Application - Permissions - Instrumentation -
>   AndroidManifest.xml), then "Add..." a "Uses Permission" and select the
>   desired permission from the dropdown on the right, or just copy paste
>   in the necessary one (such as the "android.permission.INTERNET"
>   permission you required

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: sorry,i have set the internet permission ,but it does not work.but other rest api works correctly

Comment: @Juned He has already mentioned that he has added the permission for Internet. Moreover, if Internet permission is not added then it throws `UnknownHostException`.